# What's the difference between dispatch_queue_get_specific and dispatch_get_specific?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

When should I use the former and when should I use the latter? To me they seem very similar.

Answer (score 1):

[Reading the source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.1.9/src/queue.c) it is easy to see that they behave very differently.

dispatch_queue_get_specific gets the value/context from the specific queue you pass in:

```
DISPATCH_NOINLINE
void *
dispatch_queue_get_specific(dispatch_queue_t dq, const void *key)
{
    if (slowpath(!key)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    void *ctxt = NULL;

    if (fastpath(dq->dq_specific_q)) {
        ctxt = (void *)key;
        dispatch_sync_f(dq->dq_specific_q, &ctxt, _dispatch_queue_get_specific);
    }
    return ctxt;
}
```

dispatch_get_specific gets the value/context from the current queue you are on and walks upwards the current set of queues you are on:

```
DISPATCH_NOINLINE
void *
dispatch_get_specific(const void *key)
{
    if (slowpath(!key)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    void *ctxt = NULL;
    dispatch_queue_t dq = _dispatch_queue_get_current();

    while (slowpath(dq)) {
        if (slowpath(dq->dq_specific_q)) {
            ctxt = (void *)key;
            dispatch_sync_f(dq->dq_specific_q, &ctxt,
                    _dispatch_queue_get_specific);
            if (ctxt) break;
        }
        dq = dq->do_targetq;
    }
    return ctxt;
}
```